# Сохранение исходящей почты EXIM

Tags: exim

Как настроить EXIM, чтобы он сохранял копию исходящего письма локально на сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоваться возможностью пропускать все обрабатываемые сообщения через [*системные фильтры*](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-systemwide_message_filtering.html).

задаётся их местоположение директивой где-нибудь в начале конфигурации:

```
system_filter = /путь/к/файлу/с/фильтрами
```

по поводу того, что именно вписать в этот файл для «сохранения» сообщений — есть много вариантов.

например, можно отправлять копию на какой-нибудь адрес:

```
unseen deliver user@domain
```

---

другой вариант: складывать почту в каталог ([формат maildir](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir)).

указать это можно в том же файле такой строкой:

```
unseen save /путь/к/каталогу
```

а в конфигурацию надо внести две добавки.

1. там же, где вставляли строку про путь к файлу с системными фильтрами надо добавить строку про «системно-фильтровый» транспорт:

   system_filter_file_transport = local_delivery

и ближе к началу секции, описывающей транспорты, добавить конфигурацию этого транспорта:

```
local_delivery: driver = appendfile
group = exim
user = exim
mode = 0660
maildir_format = true
```

---

подробности смотрите в документации по приведённой в начале сообщения ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Почта пересылается на мой адрес. Также, для сохранения почты в файле, я применил следующую конфигурацию:

Comment: В секции Global Macro Definitions:

system_filter = /path/to/filter
system_filter_file_transport = local_delivery

В секции Transport Configuration:

local_delivery:
driver = appendfile
group = exim
user = exim
mode = 0660
maildir_format = true

Системный фильтр(system_filter):

unseen save /path/to/folder

Comment: добавил про директиву save (из вашего комментария) в ответ.